# Visual Studio strange reference name

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

In our current 50+ project visual studio solution some of the project references are like so :

```
FulfillmentOnly.Messaging (FulfillmentOnly.Messaging\FulfillmentOnly.Messaging)
```

Instead of

```
FulfillmentOnly.Messaging
```

Sometimes two will appear like so, which causes ambiguous reference errors.

```
FulfillmentOnly.Messaging
FulfillmentOnly.Messaging (FulfillmentOnly.Messaging\FulfillmentOnly.Messaging)
```

Any idea what causes these strange Project references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this sometimes happens when you have solution folders with the same name as one of the projects, in your case FulfillmentOnly.Messaging. You can probably edit your csproj files manually, at least I seem to remember doing this myself. Visual Studio will find the correct project if you remove the extra directory part.

Good luck!